# Можно ли заинлайнить шрифты otf в тэге style?

Tags: css, node.js, css3, pdf, puppeteer

Есть задача - динамически сгенерировать строку с html кодом и на основе нее сгенерировать pdf файл (использую пакет [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)). Естественно, в этой пдфке все должно быть стилизовано так как хочет заказчик.

Заказчик предоставляет otf файлы шрифтов, которые нужны.

Внутрь тэга style я внедряю вот такую строку:

```
import { join } from "path";

const path = join(process.cwd(), "/src/templates/fonts");

export const fonts = `
@font-face {
    font-family: "proximanova";
    src: url("${ path }/ProximaNova/ProximaNova-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
`;
```

Тестирую это все дело. Для полноты картины генерирую не только pdf файл, но рядом еще кладу html файл.
Так вот когда открываю html файл в браузере, то шрифты нормально подхватываются.
А в pdf нет.

Есть ли возможность заинлайнить содержимое otf файла в тэге style?

Comment: ну да, переведи их в base64 и `src: url(data:font/opentype;charset=utf-8;base64,) format("woff");`. вот только я бы не стал брать поделку на основе фантома, перспективнее взять https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: @örbörnën спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь с данной библиотекой. А можете аргументировать, в чем недостаток фантома?

Comment: @örbörnën значит мне надо прочитать файл шрифта с диска, полученный буфер сконвертировать в строку base64, и ее записать после последней запятой в "аргументах" урла. я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @örbörnën работает, спасибо! оформите это как ответ пожалуйста - он вполне заслуживает быть принятым. (правда в пдфке шрифты все равно не подхватываются((  )

Comment: при генерации пдф с помощью wkhtmltopdf и puppeteer шрифты подхватываются и по путям, и в бейс64

Comment: @örbörnën спасибо - как раз ставлю эту библиотеку

Comment: @örbörnën а это нормально, что puppeteer  игнорирует background-color и все делает белым?

Comment: printBackground в https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions или https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2182. пользуйся гуглом